# How to draw random circles with or without custom painter without overlap on another circle and circle radius add by user in flutter?

Tags: flutter, random, stack

I have to make this type of ui.can you please give me suggestion or idea that how to make this type of ui?

[image]

Comment: have you found any solution? Please let us know